# Create copy of file in the same location

Tags: shell, cp

I often need to create copy of files in varios locations(, and want to avoid excessive typing). (Then I will edit them)

Basically commands are like:

```
cp very/long/path/to/file/my-file_with-long.name very/long/path/to/file/my-file_with-long-another.name
vim very/long/path/to/file/my-file_with-long-another.name
cp even/longer/path/to/other/location/with_another-file_and-stupid.name even/longer/path/to/other/location/with_another-file_and-stupid-copy.name
vim even/longer/path/to/other/location/with_another-file_and-stupid-copy.name
```

I really want to avoid changing workdir with `cd` and typing the same path twice. Basically I can add command into `bashrc` like `mydup`, so it will create new file and return its name, so I cam use:

```
vim $(mydup very/long/path/to/file/my-file_with-long.name -another)
vim $(mydup even/longer/path/to/other/location/with_another-file_and-stupid.name -copy)
```

But maybe I invent bicycle and there is easier way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp /very/long/file/path{,.bak}

vim !$
```

or

```
cpvi() {
    name=$1
    cp "${name}" "${name}.bak"
    $EDITOR "${name}.bak"
}

cpvi /very/long/file/path
```

Comment: oh thank you - `vim !$` is gamechanger :)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a file in-place, without changing directories. E.g.

```
cp very-long-file-name very-long-file-name.copy
vim very-long-file-name.copy
```

In this case, bash-completion and `tab` key is your friend. I do it all the time and I never write too much.

Comment: but I must  use `cd` for that (and then `cd` back) and it is really not the best solution I consider at the moment, but thx anyway

Comment: I presume that the paths are pretty unique, so bash can automatically complete it with a single `tab`?

Comment: Also, if you access same paths over times, you can just create symbolic links to a so-called warp-directory, so `/very/long/directory/name` becomes `/warp/first`.

Comment: no: there are many nested paths and many files in each

Comment: Oh, alright then. It seems that your case is different than I imagined.